# Pandas how to convert two columns to many columns and rows based on mutual row to row relationship

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say we have a df with row to row relation of some IDs, for example like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID_nm": [1, 2, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 6], 
                   "ID_lt": ["a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "d", "e", "e", "e"]})
```

With will create:

```
  ID_nm   ID_lt
0   1       a
1   1       a
2   2       b
3   2       b
4   3       c
5   4       d
6   5       e
7   5       e
```

How to set col ID_lt values to be a colums and link to them values from col1 to rows? So the output would look like this:

```
            ID_lt

ID_nm   a   b   c   d   e
        1   4   3   4   5
        2   2   -   -   1
        -   -   -   -   6
```

In other words, to convert col "ID_lt" values to columns and assign to the rows values from col "ID_nm", and fill with null values rows that can't be filled anymore due to their size?

The header and row name in the output are just to indicate which columns is which...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To extend @BERA's answer, which doesn't quite produce the table format you're looking for, you can first add a cumulative count of each `ID_lt` value with:

```py
df["ID_lt_ct"] = df.groupby("ID_lt").cumcount()
```

Which will give:

```
   ID_nm ID_lt  ID_lt_ct
0      1     a         0
1      2     a         1
2      4     b         0
3      2     b         1
4      3     c         0
5      4     d         0
6      5     e         0
7      1     e         1
8      6     e         2
```

*Then* you can run pivot with `ID_lt_ct` as the index:

```
df = df.pivot(index=['ID_lt_ct'], columns='ID_lt', values='ID_nm').fillna('-').reset_index(drop=True)
```

Giving your desired format:

```
ID_lt       a    b    c    d    e
0         1.0  4.0  3.0  4.0  5.0
1         2.0  2.0    -    -  1.0
2           -    -    -    -  6.0
```

Answer (score -1):

Pivot:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({"ID_nm": [1, 2, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 6], 
                   "ID_lt": ["a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "d", "e", "e", "e"]})

df = df.pivot(columns='ID_lt', values='ID_nm').fillna('-')

ID_lt  a  b  c  d  e
0      1  -  -  -  -
1      2  -  -  -  -
2      -  4  -  -  -
3      -  2  -  -  -
4      -  -  3  -  -
5      -  -  -  4  -
6      -  -  -  -  5
7      -  -  -  -  1
8      -  -  -  -  6
```